# PayPal API Internal Error 10002

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I've suddenly started to get internal error in PayPal Express Checkout transactions.. Im using paypal SandBox API.. I haven't changed anything in code, its just started to happen suddenly... Here is the error

```
SetExpressCheckoutResponseType Object
(
    [Token] => 
    [Timestamp] => 2013-10-14T06:19:59Z
    [Ack] => Failure
    [CorrelationID] => 7cabaf55e9cf5
    [Errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => ErrorType Object
                (
                    [ShortMessage] => Authentication/Authorization Failed
                    [LongMessage] => Internal Error
                    [ErrorCode] => 10002
                    [SeverityCode] => Error
                    [ErrorParameters] => 
                )

        )

    [Version] => 94.0
    [Build] => 8119636
 )
```

It looks like its some kind of internal error with PayPal.. But still not sure about it becuase paypal doesn't provide any kind of help for resolving this error.. See the following link

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

99% of the time, that means Paypal is down. You can check site status on [this page](https://www.paypal-notify.com/eventnotification/search?eventSearchType=PayPalSiteStatus).